# Ghost URL loaded in Ember

Tags: git, caching, ember.js

I have a weird behaviour. We are working with Ember on Git for a while now, but in this new project, I'm having for the first time an issue following the below steps:

1. Add a new .svg image and **delete the old .png**
2. Then I change all references to the .png with the .svg image name
3. Check that is working. It does
4. git add .
5. git commit -m "my message"
6. git pull [branch]
7. git push [branch]
8. Go back to the browser and images are broken
9. Look at the generated code and src URL is pointing to the old .png image

We find

```
<img class="logo" src="./assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
```

instead of:

```
<img class="logo" src="./assets/images/logo.svg" alt="logo">
```

10. Ask **my partner** to get my code in the branch and check if he's getting the same issue. He doesn't, **he sees the new .svg image**.
11. **I deleted the local branch and bring it back again. The issue is gone**.
12. I do some changes and pull again and then the issue comes back.

I have the following code in the template.hbs

```
<img class="logo" src="{{logo}}" alt="logo">
```

and this in the `component`:

```
logo: computed('logo', function() {
  return htmlSafe('./assets/images/' + ((config.APP.logo) ? config.APP.logo : 'logo.svg'));
})
```

This is calling to an environment condition that determines the logo that have to be loaded.

Did this happen to any of you? Do you have any idea of how to prevent this happen?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with local browser cache caused by not fingerprinting the assets. May also be caused by a service worker having a cache-first policy.

Comment: I cleaned the local storage "hundred" times and that didn't solved the problem. I have no record of us using that kind of policies, but I'll check with my partner.
Thanks @jelhan

Comment: does this have something to do with `ghost` ?

Comment: you find the old `<img` in the *code* or in the *browser*? Could you verify you and your partner actually have the *same commit id*? Does restarting the ember server help (instead of deleting your branch)?

Comment: In the browser, while in the code was the proper one as explained above. Restarting the ember server didn't help, only deleting the branch and getting it back from remote. By now I haven't experiment the issue again as I'm on holidays. I'll update here with any new info a have.
Thanks